# Having trouble setting the state in a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a series of promises in my `componentDidMount()` function. In the `values.then(function(result)` promise, I am trying to set the state. I get this error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` but researched this error and I need to bind my promise using an arrow function to give it access to the `this` keyword.

```
componentDidMount() {
        let general = {};
        let values = [];
        //gets selected setting form schema
        getSettingsForms().then((response) => {
            this.setState({settingsForms: response});
            general = response[this.state.selectedSetting];
        }).then(response => {
            values = getSettingsConfig(this.state.selectedSetting, general);
            values.then(function(result) {
                this.setState({
                    formSchema: result[1],
                    selectedSetting: this.state.selectedSetting,
                    settings: result[0]

                })

            })
        })
    }
```

The problem is that I don't know where to put the arrow function on this sort of promise. Anywhere I put it, I get an error saying `Unexpected token, expected "{"` and then when I try put the curly brace in, I get another error.

```
componentDidMount() {
        let general = {};
        let values = [];
        //gets selected setting form schema
        getSettingsForms().then((response) => {
            this.setState({settingsForms: response});
            general = response[this.state.selectedSetting];
        }).then(response => {
            values = getSettingsConfig(this.state.selectedSetting, general);
            values.then(function(result) => {
                this.setState({
                    formSchema: result[1],
                    selectedSetting: this.state.selectedSetting,
                    settings: result[0]

                })

            })
        })
    }
```

What is the correct way to put in this arrow function to the `values.then(function(result)` promise so that I can then set the state?
`

Answer (score 1):

Just like the other two arrow functions you are using:

```
componentDidMount() {
        let general = {};
        let values = [];
        //gets selected setting form schema
        getSettingsForms().then((response) => {
            this.setState({settingsForms: response});
            general = response[this.state.selectedSetting];
        }).then(response => {
            values = getSettingsConfig(this.state.selectedSetting, general);
            values.then(result => {
                this.setState({
                    formSchema: result[1],
                    selectedSetting: this.state.selectedSetting,
                    settings: result[0]

                })

            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't need that function in there.